# How to run python files on tomcat server?

Tags: python, tomcat, cgi

I have installed Tomcat in my system and when I type "http://localhost:8081/"
I get the following screen

[image]

However when I try to run a .py file from Tomcat, it is unable to interpret the file and shows me the following screen. What should I do to resolve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat doesn't know how to run Python scripts without additional configuration. You need to [configure Tomcat's `CGIServlet`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/cgi-howto.html) in order to run Python scripts.

Comment: Why the downvote? It doesn't make any sense to put a whole cookbook in an SO answer. Configuring the `CGIServlet` is fairly straightforward.

Comment: Not sure about the downvote, but enabling CGI sounds dangerous per the docs,CAUTION - CGI scripts are used to execute programs external to the Tomcat JVM. If you are using the Java SecurityManager this will bypass your security policy configuration in catalina.policy.

Comment: @MikePone Of course it's dangerous, but it's the only way to do it. The other option is "don't use Python" which would be kind of a crappy answer to the OP's question.